# mvn dependency:tree prompt invalid JAVA_HOME directory error

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, environment-variables

I am trying to access the `mvn:dependency:tree` in my `window cmd`

And it prompts me the following error:
[image: err1]

Then I tried to check my `Java` installed location by doing so:

[image: err2]

So does this proves that my `JAVA_HOME` is setting at the correct directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51`

Note : The Problem is that you are pointing to the `jre/bin`. You have to remove it and just point to the directory path till `jdk1.7.0_51` (`JAVA_HOME`)